# Can Doxygen escape HTML tags?

Tags: html, doxygen

I want to include a literal HTML element in a Doxygen comment. Something like this:

```
/// This function skips all <li> elements
```

If I write it like that, the `<li>` is passed to the HTML output, which is obviously not what I want.

Instead, I can write this:

```
/// This function skips all &lt;li&gt; elements
```

This works fine in the HTML generated by Doxygen, but now the comment in the source code itself is rather illegible.

So it looks like I have to choose between legibility in the generated documentation or in the source code.

Is that really the case, or is there a way to force Doxygen to automatically turn all `<blabla>` into `&lt;blabla&gt;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also have used:

```
/// This function skips all \<li\> elements
```

Or (if `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT=YES`) write:

```
/// This function skips all `<li>` elements
```

which are both reasonably readable, or put everything in a `\verbatim..\endverbatim` section, but then it is also rendered as such.

You could also define an an alias, i.e.

```
ALIASES = verb{1}="\<\1\>"
```

And then write

```
/// This function skips all \verb{li} elements
```